# Does Laravel sets a Cookie for CSRF token

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cookies, laravel-5.3, csrf-protection

I want to get CSRF token from cookie that laravel set with XSRF-Token key. (as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-x-xsrf-token))

but I think this cookie contains something else as its length is quite larger then a normal Laravel CSRF Token.

Also, I think there is some problem with my laravel App. because it sends two set-cookie headers in response.

Here is what laravel sends in set-cookie response headers.

```
Set-Cookie: dsss=eyJpdiI6InFQQjdtUDN0TG1NZTNqZjZaY3MwMXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiR2hzaVwvUTJlQ28yTTVqVFJUeG5QcDBINnRcLzB6VEZpXC9MSGRnQktaRHNCY0U4SFwvQ01DZ0hJYVZrcjFMT21jaE5obkpMTUVTM1Eyc0pPRzhTdkJcL2ZYUT09IiwibWFjIjoiZDI5ZGQxMjYyZjZmN2MyMjk5YzFmNmVjNDRhNjkwY2VhNGRjZjBhN2E0NWM1MTFmYjVhMjA2Y2YzYmU3ZjFiMCJ9; expires=Mon, 18-Jun-2018 08:51:39 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Im4ra21yZlFGRWZjZ2YrQjE5WVdUMXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRlQ0ZHFaVk9idEY2K3hEV3hxSExsZjNKZ080cjhiTFEwdGZFK3RaOGgxOSs3dHNLRmRhcThZVFwvZ3J2ZFpxdG1VYjY2UjBobzEraTNZRm1Ha1ZUeGtRPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI5YzAzNWFhMjE0ZjBiYTM4MzE2OTFkNDYyYmZlYTc4NzdjNjc1YmMxODZkYzliZTkzZDI0MjQ3NzY4YjhhMmNlIn0%3D; expires=Mon, 18-Jun-2018 08:51:39 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
```

Also, I renamed laravel_session cookie to dsss.

I can not use meta tags to store cookies because all my html is being cached. But I can send fresh response headers.

**Updated**

I've renamed laravel_session back to its original name, But it still sends two set-cookie headers.

```
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlhRRUt3SDIrUXc0UGpSRVB0b1ZBUEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMWtsckVTZ2JRWlNXaXBkWG96WFhsMG00bVFBOHMxSUFaTGEwMlZtMkZPYmdZdks4bWpKTjdURktBanhBNjhsQUZTb1BFaVNacEkySDFOQTRCTUw1RUE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjlkNTVjODdkMTQwYTQ3ZTkxOTNjYjljZDc3NTU3MjE5MTg2OTM5ODhjOTg0YjE0ODYyZjBhNzc1YTkzOWIxZDAifQ%3D%3D; expires=Mon, 18-Jun-2018 10:37:42 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImNxOTdCNkIydmFHbmlYRFVnYUdlb2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiOUFWWmc5QkFGV1RrWUp6TzlNTUFaWFhhaFUyd0tyYTlFeE9XZWhRUzZ1ZnNHZTJDK3paRmtWdkNOQ1FERmVJKzNxVjZRMGRHemRjSXZMWU1sK1R6T0E9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjYyYjBlNTgwNDY0NzYxNjVlOWQ0MWE2NDFiYWU2NjI1NWUwYjY2MTAyNmYyNmZhOGU2ZGE1NDg3ZGQ1YjljMmEifQ%3D%3D; expires=Mon, 18-Jun-2018 10:37:42 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Comment: You can use Cookie::get('token') or Session::token() , Laravel encrypts the tokens. Using the default functions will automatically decrypt the token. Laravel also automatically stores the XSRF token as in your code example. Because you rename it and then send it again it will show up twice.

Comment: Ok I've renamed laravel_session back to laravel_session. But it still sending two set-cookie header twice.

Comment: The double cookie is normal, that is because you send another cookie. If you remove that line of code it will only have 1 cookie.

Comment: I'm not sending any set-cookie header.

Comment: Can you share another screenshot of the headers please. Is it the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs:

> This cookie is primarily sent as a convenience since some JavaScript frameworks and libraries, like Angular and Axios, automatically place its value in the X-XSRF-TOKEN header.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-x-xsrf-token

Answer (score 1):

Actually the csrf token automatically will store in cookies . If you want to retrieve it use this php function

> echo $_COOKIE['XSRF-TOKEN'];