# laravel 6 csrf token expired in every 60 seconds?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, csrf, csrf-token

I am using **laravel 6**.I Want my **laravel CSRF Token expire in every 60 seconds**.

config/session

'lifetime' => 60,

Comment: Which SESSION_DRIVER are you using?
Case csrf token will expire by default

Comment: Yes , It will be expired in 1 week but i want expired in 1 minute.

Comment: Okay just put SESSION_LIFETIME=1 in your .env file

Comment: No working, Already checked.

Comment: Can you give me the whole Scenario

Comment: have you ran `php artisan config:cache` command?

Answer (score 5):

First of All, CSRF is stored in XSRF-TOKEN cookie. Ref: [50904763](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904763/does-laravel-sets-a-cookie-for-csrf-token)

According to the question (Ref: [51615122](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51615122/laravel-csrf-expiry-time)), We change the configuration in app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php by adding a new method named `addCookieToResponse`

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;

public function addCookieToResponse($request, $response) {
    $config = config('session');
    $session_life = env('CSRF_LIFE');

    $response->headers->setCookie(
        new Cookie(
            'XSRF-TOKEN', $request->session()->token(), $this->availableAt($session_life),
            $config['path'], $config['domain'], $config['secure'], false, false, $config['same_site'] ?? null
        )
    );
}
```

where `$config` is used to get session information from existing lifetime. However, I parse `$session_life` from *.env* to make sure you can customize as much as you can.

So, the result is simple, configure everything as belongs but in area `$this->availableAt($session_life)` where `session_life` is in seconds.

So, please set `session_life` to 60 in .env as below:

```
CSRF_LIFE="60"
```

After you save and refresh your page, or clean cache and configs, Session LifeTime will be two hours but CSRF will be only 60 secs.

Hope this works.

[image: CSRF Cookie Time on 1 Minute]

Answer (score 0):

After long testing I end up something, that you put in the `lifetime` option in session not allow to set expire time in seconds, it'll allow to minutes.

So, when you set up `lifetime = "60"`, it's means it will expire in 1 hour.

Hence, You have to set `lifetime = "1"` in your `config/session.php` file. Also, default value in `.env` file `SESSION_LIFETIME=120` you have to replace that with 1 `SESSION_LIFETIME = 1`.

After that you have to clear the cache by command:

`php artisan config:cache`

Now, your session will expire after 1 minute / 60 secs.

To see more check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071747/how-to-set-session-timeout-in-laravel).